# How to make text's vertical alignment be centered depending on a image's height?

Tags: vertical-alignment

I tried wrapfig and minipage but wrapfig gives me collisions while minipages don't center the text to the image properly.

Example with minipage:

```
\documentclass[14pt,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Insert image
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\subsubsection{Step 1}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{.22\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=.2\textheight,width=1\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.76\textwidth}
        Very little text here. About a sentence or two... maybe three.
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\subsubsection{Step 2}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{.22\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=.2\textheight,width=1\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.76\textwidth}
        \lipsum[66]
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\subsubsection{Step 3}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{.22\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=.2\textheight,width=1\linewidth]{example-image-c}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.76\textwidth}
        \lipsum[75]
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I obtained this [image: result with minipage]

While I want [image: this]

Comment: in your B you have aligned the centre of the image with the first row of the text which looks odd, just remove the `[t]` so they are both centred.

Comment: Oh thanks... it actually fixed it. (I'm new to latex and I thought that [t] was mandatory for text when it comes to minipages... guess it was for vertical alignment also.)

Comment: no, it just means top

Comment: By the way, you're misusing `figure`: just a `center` environment suffices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An different approach to construct your images with text: use `tabularx`, accordingly redefine column types and you can obtain:

[image]

```
\documentclass[14pt,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Insert image
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{plain}

    \usepackage{tabularx}% <-- new
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\small}m{#1}}% <-- new
%    \usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}
\subsubsection{Step 1}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\hsize=0.24\hsize\centering}X
                            >{\hsize=0.76\hsize}X}
\includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image-a}
    &
Very little text here. About a sentence or two... maybe three.
\end{tabularx}
    \end{figure}

\subsubsection{Step 2}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\hsize=0.24\hsize\centering}X
                            >{\hsize=0.76\hsize}X}
\includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image-b}
    &
\lipsum[66]
\end{tabularx}
    \end{figure}

\subsubsection{Step 3}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\hsize=0.24\hsize\centering}X
                            >{\hsize=0.76\hsize}X}
\includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image-c}
    &
\lipsum[75]
\end{tabularx}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to specify a vertical limit for the images with this code?like includegraphics' height=.3\textheight?

Comment: yes, it is possible. suggested solution hasn't any restriction in use of`\includegraphics` options/parameters.

Answer (score 2):

In your B you have aligned the centre of the image with the first row of the text which looks odd, just remove the `[t]` so they are both centred